# How to Record Android Screen Video programmatically in KitKat 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, screen-capture

I know this question has been asked so many times and there are so many questions, answers and discussions available. But I don't know what to do and what not to do.

I already referred to the links below to get solution with no luck.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438767/how-to-record-video-on-kitkat-4-4
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185125/i-cannot-screen-record-with-my-kitkat-4-4-moto-x
[Android KitKat start screenrecord from App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330237/android-kitkat-start-screenrecord-from-app)
[screen recorder with kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800742/screen-recorder-with-kitkat)
[Screen Recording kitkat with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326522/screen-recording-kitkat-with-button)

With lots of search I didn't get any simple example to achieve this task. Since 2 days i am trying to achieve this but with no success.

So the simple question is whether it is possible to record video of our own screen in android. I just heard that it is possible from android 4.4 Kitkat and i also check some app from market.

I know to do this our device should be rooted and other things which required to do this.

But I am not getting how to develop this programmatically. If any one have any idea then please guide me how to do this. or any example or code will be great help.

I appreciate your any kind of help.

I try to develop with this simple piece of code but not getting anything

```
public void startRecording(View v) {
        File recordfolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String record = "su      — bit rate 8000000 --time-limit 30 "
                + recordfolder + "Record.mp4";
        recordfolder.mkdir();
        try {
            Process screenrecording = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(record);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

so basically I don't know what i have to do with this `Process screenrecording`, I mean how can I start progress.

Comment: I'm also interested in knowing this, preferably without root requirements.

Comment: Hey @user3660803, It's been a long time since this question has been asked. Did you have any new insights since then ?

Answer (score 9):

Good Question But the answer depends on what type of platform you want to use to record the screen in android.

**Here are some tricks.....**

**1)** Using this class you can record the screen fort that you required rooted device you can test this in genymotion 4.4 also.

```
public static class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context mContext;

    private EditText mWidthEditText;
    private EditText mHeightEditText;
    private EditText mBitrateEditText;
    private EditText mTimeEditText;
    private Button mRecordButton;

    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        mContext = getActivity();

        mRecordButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_record);
        mRecordButton.setOnClickListener(RecordOnClickListener);

        mWidthEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_width);
        mHeightEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_height);
        mBitrateEditText = (EditText) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.et_bitrate);
        mBitrateEditText.addTextChangedListener(BitrateTextWatcher);
        mTimeEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_time);
        mTimeEditText.addTextChangedListener(TimeTextWatcher);

        return rootView;
    }

    private TextWatcher BitrateTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,
                int i2, int i3) {
            // Not used.
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2,
                int i3) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence)) {
                return;
            }

            int value = Integer.valueOf(charSequence.toString());
            if (value > 50 || value == 0) {
                mBitrateEditText.setError(mContext
                        .getString(R.string.error_bitrate_edittext));
                return;
            }

            mTimeEditText.setError(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // Not used.
        }
    };

    private TextWatcher TimeTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,
                int i2, int i3) {
            // Not used.
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2,
                int i3) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence)) {
                return;
            }

            int value = Integer.valueOf(charSequence.toString());
            if (value > 180 || value == 0) {
                mTimeEditText.setError(mContext
                        .getString(R.string.error_time_editext));
                return;
            }
            mTimeEditText.setError(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // Not used.
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener RecordOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mTimeEditText.getError())
                    || !TextUtils.isEmpty(mBitrateEditText.getError())) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        mContext.getString(R.string.toast_invalid_values),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            boolean widthSet = !TextUtils.isEmpty(mWidthEditText.getText());
            boolean heightSet = !TextUtils.isEmpty(mHeightEditText
                    .getText());
            if ((!widthSet && heightSet) || (widthSet && !heightSet)) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        mContext.getString(R.string.error_invalid_wxh),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            boolean bitrateSet = !TextUtils.isEmpty(mBitrateEditText
                    .getText());
            boolean timeSet = !TextUtils.isEmpty(mTimeEditText.getText());

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(
                    "/system/bin/screenrecord");
            if (widthSet) {
                stringBuilder.append(" --size ")
                        .append(mWidthEditText.getText()).append("x")
                        .append(mHeightEditText.getText());
            }
            if (bitrateSet) {
                stringBuilder.append(" --bit-rate ").append(
                        mBitrateEditText.getText());
            }
            if (timeSet) {
                stringBuilder.append(" --time-limit ").append(
                        mTimeEditText.getText());
            }

            // TODO User definable location.
            stringBuilder
                    .append(" ")
                    .append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .toString()).append("/recording.mp4");
            Log.d("TAG", "comamnd: " + stringBuilder.toString());

            try {
                new SuTask(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes("ASCII"))
                        .execute();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    private class SuTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean> {
        private final byte[] mCommand;

        public SuTask(byte[] command) {
            super();
            this.mCommand = command;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... booleans) {
            try {
                Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
                OutputStream outputStream = sh.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(mCommand);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                        createRunningNotification(mContext));

                sh.waitFor();
                return true;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        mContext.getString(R.string.error_start_recording),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        mContext.getString(R.string.error_start_recording),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {
            super.onPostExecute(bool);
            if (bool) {
                final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.cancel(RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID);

                File file = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/recording.mp4");
                notificationManager.notify(FINISHED_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                        createFinishedNotification(mContext, file));
            }
        }

        private Notification createRunningNotification(Context context) {
            Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
                    context)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sdcard)
                    .setContentTitle(
                            context.getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText("Recording Running")
                    .setTicker("Recording Running")
                    .setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE).setOngoing(true);

            return mBuilder.build();
        }

        private Notification createFinishedNotification(Context context,
                File file) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/mp4");

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
                    context)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sdcard)
                    .setContentTitle(
                            context.getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText("Recording Finished")
                    .setTicker("Recording Finished")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setOngoing(false)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            return mBuilder.build();
        }
    }
}
```

**2)** You can capture the screen shots and make the video from it and it will work for the 3.0+ devices And for converting the images to video you can use FFMPEG or JavaCV.

-**For Rooted devices(in that you can capture the keyboard screen also)**

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
            .getExternalStorageState())) {

        // we check if external storage is\ available, otherwise
        // display an error message to the user using Toast Message
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/ScreenShots");
        directory.mkdirs();

        String filename = "screenshot_jpeg_" + i + ".png";
        File yourFile = new File(directory, filename);



        try {
            Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
            OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
            os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/ScreenShots/" + filename).getBytes("ASCII"));


            os.flush();
            os.close();
            sh.waitFor();
            i++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

-**For without Rooted devices(in that you can not capture the keyboard screen)**

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
            .getExternalStorageState())) {

        // we check if external storage is\ available, otherwise
        // display an error message to the user using Toast Message
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/ScreenShots");
        directory.mkdirs();

        String filename = "screenshot_jpeg_" + i + ".png";
        File yourFile = new File(directory, filename);



        try {
            Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
            OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
            os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/ScreenShots/" + filename).getBytes("ASCII"));


            os.flush();
            os.close();
            sh.waitFor();
            i++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code for with and without root are identical. Did you mean to call `su` in the last example?

Comment: @emkman Yes you have to give the su permission for the rooted devices.

Comment: Yes but what about the unrooted device (no keyboard). Your two examples are identical.

Comment: The first set of code works for me using genymotion 4.4

Please also note to change the external storage path to /mnt/shell/emulated/0 instead of using Environment.getExternalStorage() when testing it with genymotion 4.4 or a rooted 4.4 device emulator

Check this answer for more details on the directory path change http://stackoverflow.com/a/20734816/2644384

Comment: @uncannyj Thanks you can up vote the answer if you got helped.

Comment: @SmitPatel it seems that you can't screenrecord using any emulator. I wasn't able to use genymotion to record but I was able to produce a .mp4 file so when I tested it with a rooted 4.4 android phone it worked well based on your code 1. Thanks!

Comment: @SmitPatel how do I prematurely end the screen recording?

Comment: @JaysonTamayo which of the method from above are you using?

Comment: @SmitPatel For the rooted device. using the method native to android 4.4

Comment: @SmitPatel After I click the button (where i put your code). A notification says running then evntually it says 'finished'. When I click the notification it says 'Cant play the video'. What's happening?

Comment: @uncannyj Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: @JaysonTamayo please manually follow first to the PATH and check the video is there or not then pass that link in the method of that particular PATH.

Comment: @SmitPatel your example for without rooted the same for rooted

Comment: @NguyenThanhAn the only difference is you can not capture the keyboard screen for without rooted devices

Comment: @SmitPatel :  I found exception on device without root : null inviroment in line : "Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);"

Comment: @NguyenThanhAn I also got the IOException on non-rooted device in "Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);". Any idea how to solve this?