# Programmatically how to create Video in android

Tags: android, video, screen, video-recording

I want to create an application that will enable to record screen behavior as a video that will be save  programmatically on the device. Can any one help me for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices, for obvious privacy and security reasons. An app cannot record what other apps show on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For a rooted device you can take screenshots and make a video based on those screenshots using FFMPEG or JavaCV.

Actually this topic have been discussed several times.

Here's an example of How to get root access and get your screenshot.

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
        .getExternalStorageState())) {

    // we check if external storage is\ available, otherwise
    // display an error message to the user using Toast Message
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/ScreenShots");
    directory.mkdirs();

    String filename = "screenshot_jpeg_" + i + ".png";
    File yourFile = new File(directory, filename);



    try {
        Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
        OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
        os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/ScreenShots/" + filename).getBytes("ASCII"));


        os.flush();
        os.close();
        sh.waitFor();
        i++;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can check other solutions on the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800030/how-to-record-android-screen-video-programmatically-in-kitkat-4-4) and [here](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f) for FFMPEG