# Call screenrecord within android app on samsung device not working

Tags: android, shell, samsung-mobile, nexus-5, screen-recording

I am using the screenrecord api from android within my app.

Therefor i have read several good **[postings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800030/how-to-record-android-screen-video-programmatically-in-kitkat-4-4)**

On a rooted Nexus 5 (Android 5.1) the code below works without any problems. That means that the screen record gets triggered and the video is saved succesfully to the sdcard.

On a rooted Samsung S6 Edge (Android 5.0.2) the code will stuck at the first call of *readLine()*. The mp4 file is created and can be found on the sdcard but it is empty.

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Here my code:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();

    InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

    stdin.write(("/system/bin/screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/recording.mp4\n").getBytes());

    stdin.write("exit\n".getBytes());

    stdin.flush();   //flush stream
    stdin.close(); //close stream

    String line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i("Response: ", line);
        mResults.append(line);
    }
    br.close();

    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.e("Error: ", line);
        mErrors.append(line);
    }
    br.close();

} catch(IOException ioe) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + ioe.toString());
}
```

So I searched the web and found out that it might be the problem that there is just nothing to be read. I added "&& echo done" to the shell command but still no change.

I checked the log several times and I found two lines with *KNOX* in it:

> I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10202
>
> I/libpersona﹕KNOX_SDCARD not a persona

I thought maybe KNOX prevents my app from writing to the sdcard. So I deleted KNOX from the device but the same problem still occurred.

I need to get this code running on this particular Samsung device.
Hopefully some of you have an idea how to get the code running.

Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution for the described particular problem.
But I stumbled over another API that helped me to achieve my goal and record the screen of an android device.

With the help of the [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) and the [VirtualDisplay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/VirtualDisplay.html) I was able to capture the screen into a mp4-file onto the sdcard.