# How can I use media projection for older api?

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

I want to record the screen contents for 1 min. After searching google, I found that the api level **21** contains `MediaProjecion` class. My app is build for api level **18**.

Can I use this class? Is there any support library for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I use this class?

No.

> Is there any support library for this?

No.

Comment: thanks . can you suggest any link where i can get how to capture screen video . i am following this link 
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800030/how-to-record-android-screen-video-programmatically-in-kitkat-4-4 but it is only for kit-kat' and above

Comment: @NumaFitness: Outside of rooted devices, an Android SDK app cannot capture screen video prior to Android 5.0.

Comment: it is ok even if the mobile has to be rooted all i want to do is record a screen video for 1 min

Comment: You can run the `screenrecord` app on Android 4.4 (using `su -c` to switch away from the app's user ID). With minor changes the command can be used on Android 4.3, but you'd have to install it yourself.

Comment: but this will make it compulsory that the user should have the screenrecord app. how can i record the screen from my app

Comment: is there any library available to create such a video, i searched for ffmpeg but i am not understanding how to work with it ,is there any other solution