# full screen on video capture android

Tags: android, fullscreen, video-capture

[image]I need full screen on Video Capture but I am unable to do.I am posting my code.please help me

```
  public void startRecordingVideo() {
    if (getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        File mediaFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
        videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "No camera on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800030/how-to-record-android-screen-video-programmatically-in-kitkat-4-4

Comment: @Karthik user is not looking for screen recording, he need full screen record mode in video intent

Comment: This worked for me https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

Comment: where is the full screen code in the link?

Comment: check my answer @user8601021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) documentation ,

**EXTRA_FULL_SCREEN**

> The name of an Intent-extra used to control the UI of a ViewImage.
>   This is a boolean property that overrides the activity's default
>   fullscreen state.

And there is one more case where it give the padding is because of the camera resolution, in my case if i use 320*240 it is giving the same padding but if i use the 1280*720 or more than that it is not showing any padding and fitting the full screen.

For this you can use `MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` parameter to set the video quality also.

So in your case try to use like this ,

```
 public void startRecordingVideo() {
    if (getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        File mediaFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
        videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FULL_SCREEN , true);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "No camera on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I still see the padding on both sides of the camera during recording video and also showing video.

Comment: ASAIK this is the only way to set the full screen mode for video through the Intent. are you talking about the video recording time / after saved video with in the video your seeing padding ?

Comment: I have edited my question with a screenshot of the recording screen with padding on both sides.Please check it and help me.